# How to make a program to calculate this equation

Tags: c++

Hello I'm a beginner in C++, and I need to make a program to calculate this equation. Can anybody help me? `A` and `M` reads from the keyboard

Equation:

[image]

I tried with this code:

```
int M = 1;
int A;
cin >> A;
cin >> M;
float sum;
for(int i = 1; i<=M; k++){
    k = k*i;
    float A1 = pow(A, i);
    sum += A1 / k;
}
```

Comment: Please understand that StackOverflow is meant to help you by answering specific question on programming problems you have encountered whiole programming yourself. Or to put it differently, not to write programs for you. Please show what you have tried and explain in detail where you are stuck. If your problem is "No idea where to start" then the question is off-topic for being too broad to be answered, because any helpful question would amount to a C++ tutorial.

Comment: Thank you  @Robin Schwendele

Comment: Good edit. :-) Now it is an acceptable question. And it got you at least one helpful answer. Nice to see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. At first, it will not compile, because the variable `k` is undefined.
Next, there is an endles loop, because of `k++` instead of `i++`.
And third, `sum` is not initialized (with 1, if you start your `i` and `k` at 1, too).

so your modified code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int M, A;
    cout << "A: "; cin >> A;
    cout << "M: "; cin >> M;
    float sum = 1;
    int k = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= M; i++)
    {
        k = k * i;
        float A1 = pow(A, i);
        sum +=  A1 / k;
    }
    cout << "result: " << sum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the 3 obvious issues (infinite loop, missed initialization, missing function declaration) already listed above, we can optimize performance by calculating A^k iteratively, rather than re-calculating in each step:

```
#include <stdio.h>

auto combinations(float A, unsigned short M) {
    float ret_val = 1.0f;                  // For k=0: A^0 / 0! = 1
    float num = A;  
    float denum = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= M; ) {
        ret_val += num / denum;
        num *= A;
        denum *= ++k;
    }
    return ret_val;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Value for A=2, M=10: %f\n\r", combinations(2.0f, 10));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are usually not considered helpful. They tend to spread the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code writing service. Please augment it with some explanation. Why and how does your proposal solve the problem.